# Reading property file in java using Spring

Tags: spring

1. Have been trying to understand how to load a property file using Spring in java and populate `java.util.Properties` object.
2. Use this newly created property object as a constructor arguement for another bean.

Appreciate any pointers on this.

Thanks,
cabear

Comment: Paste your name.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

To load a properties file in Spring use the `PropertiesFactoryBean` to make it easier to use there is a `properties` tag in the `util` namespace you can use.

```
<util:properties id="props" location="location-of.properties" />
```

Then you have a bean named `props` which you can use as any regular bean.

```
<bean id="otherBean" class="my.app.MyClass" >
    <constructor-arg ref="props" />
</bean>
```

When also using the property placeholder support you could use the same properties object again instead of loading it again, by referencing it using the `properties-ref` attribute of the `property-placeholder` tag.

```
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="props" />
```

Comment: Is the props reloadable?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you read a properties file :

```
@Value("${memberaddedsubject}") // id of the content you want to read.
    private String memberAddedSubject; // Taking content in String class.
```

To use this property file, you have to instruct spring, this way :

```
  <util:properties id="props" location="your-location-to-props" />
```

Add the above line in your applicationContext.xml or the XML file you have(not web.xml)

I have put my properties file in /projectname/resources/.

I hope this is what you are looking for, if not, let me know.

Comment: Well actually no that isn't the way to read a properties file. This is if you want to use the placeholder support. If you simply want to load a properties file use the util namespace. `<util:properties id="props" location="your-location-to-props" />` this will load a file and make it available as a bean.

Comment: @M.Deinum : Cool, thanks for the info, does the way to access the values inside the properties file remains the same or do I have to make some changes in that?

Comment: Thanks will try it out. In my requirement I have to read a local proeprty file p1, connect to an external system to get p2 and use p2 to initiate another bean. Any pointers on how to do this.

Comment: Another usecase: Have bean1 with props p1 and p2. Prop p1 is loaded through bean configuration. Prop p2 is loaded communicating to external system and should be used to populated prop p3 of Bean bean2. Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: @WeareBorg that just loads a properties object which you can hookup to the `<context:property-placeholder />` using the `properties-ref` attribute.

Comment: @cbear please don't use comments to ask question, open a new one for that or improve your original question if it was different in the first place.